# Is there a way to get user coordinates from telegram bot using Dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, telegram-bot

Currently im working on a telegram bot with Dialogflow. I want to get information about the user like current coordinates and user name but im not able to get them in the JSON coming from telegram. Is there a way to do such a thing without using any related google assistant events?

Comment: user should send you current location; you can get it like `update.message.location`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the structure of updates received by bot on the documentation [Telegram Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api)

`update.message.from` contains the [`User`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#user) object.

`update.message.location` contains the [`Location`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#location) object.

Be aware that the location will be present only if the user actually sent his position to the bot, it will not be a metadata coming along with every message.