# How to get user location from Telegram, using DialogFlow

Tags: dialogflow-es, telegram

I'm trying to get user location from Telegram while using DialogFlow, at the moment I'm sending Telegram the following custom payload.

I've tried the DialogFlow documentation and I'm able to retrieve user location using Facebook Messenger, through FACEBOOK_LOCATION native event.

```
  "telegram": {
    "text": "Selecione a opção desejada:",
    "reply_markup": {
      "keyboard": [
        [
          {
            "text": "Compartilhar sua Localização",
            "callback_data": "location",
            "request_location": true
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            "text": "Cancelar",
            "callback_data": "Cancelar"
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

It's expected to retrieve user's location from Telegram.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not able to do that. For example, there are `actions_intent_PERMISSION` and `actions_intent_PERMISSION` for location on Actions on Google as well. Yet, these won't be working on other platforms. As far as I know, every platform has different events and Telegram has only `TELEGRAM_WELCOME`, `TELEGRAM_HELP` and `TELEGRAM_SETTINGS`.

For more details and platform events, you can visit: [Platfom Events](https://dialogflow.com/docs/events/platform-events)

Comment: Also found this, it may be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56152226/is-there-a-way-to-get-user-coordinates-from-telegram-bot-using-dialogflow

Comment: I have seen this question before, but it only works if I'm able to receive data on my backend, and unfortunately, since DialogFlow is not able to hit the webhook intent, I have no way of receiving it on the backend.
I mean, DialogFlow does not consider the geolocation response as a response at all.